# Git: pull files from remote but do not add to .git/metadata

Tags: git

- I have a remote repository "shared_stuff" and a repository
  "project_a".
- the directory structure is the same in both repositories but the content is different
- From time to time I want to pull the changes from
  "shared_stuff" into "project_a".
- All changes in "shared_stuff" should overwrite
  eventually already existing files in "project_a"
- BUT the changes/new files should not be added to the "git metadata" of "project_a", i.e. they should not become part of "project_a"
- without git I would copy all files from "shared_stuff" into "project_a" overwriting everything in project_a

Is there a elegant solution with git? Subtree oder Submodule does not work as far as I can see.

Edit: Clarification - the changes are NOT supposed to be added to the index of project_a, I never want to commit them in project_a. On the contrary, I will add a gitignore file to project_a so that git ignores the changes I retrieved from shared_stuff (I can recognize them via naming conventions)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two remotes for you repos `project_a` and `shared_stuff`, then
you can create local branch for `shared_stuff` repo and pull changes to local branch only: `git branch shared_stuff-master shared_stuff/master` (I suppose you will use `master` branch, replace it if not). Then you can [squah merge] shared branch into primary branch and push it to `project_a`:

```sh
git checkout -b shared_stuff-master shared_stuff/master
git pull shared_stuff master
git checkout -b master project_a/master
git merge --no-commit --squash shared_stuff-master
git commit -m "merged changes from shared_stuff"
git push project_a master
```

So you'll not publish references from `shared_stuff` repo to `project_a` repo, only changed files will be published.

Comment: I added a clarification to my question explaining that I do not want to add the changes to project_a, I want to ignore them via .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is both easier and harder than you expect.  It's easier because Git doesn't *store* changes at all.  Git just stores *commits*.  It's harder because you *will* have to get things into (some) Git metadata, somewhere—or else just bypass Git entirely for this particular operation.  Unless you *do* bypass Git entirely for this particular operation, adding entries to `.gitignore` will not be fruitful.

#### Behind-the-scenes basics

Let me try to clarify what's going on behind the scenes.  Git's storage system is all about *commits* rather than files.  Each commit *stores* (some set of) files, as a complete snapshot.  Each commit also stores some per-commit metadata: who made it (author and committer), when (two date-and-time-stamps for author and committer), and why (the log message).  Each commit is uniquely identified by its (unique) hash ID.  Each commit *also* stores the unique hash ID(s) of its immediate parent commit or commits.

These hash IDs, stored in each commit and pointing backwards to some earlier commit(s), form the history in a Git repository.  That is, if you've just made a new commit in your repository, on your `master` branch, that new commit has some big ugly hash ID that is unique to it.  Let's call this hash ID `H`.  Inside commit `H` itself, there is a line that says "my parent commit is ______": fill in the blank with the raw hash ID of the commit you had checked out as your `master` before you made the new commit, but let's just call that commit `G` for convenience.  Commit `G`, of course, will have yet another parent-commit hash ID inside it: let's call that `F`.  If every commit is in a nice neat simple line (there are no branches and merges), and we draw them, we get:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the *last* commit in this line.  It points back to its parent `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit ever made—which we can call `A`.  Since that's the first commit, it cannot and therefore does not have an earlier commit: it points to nothing else, and is called a *root commit*.

In order to *find* which commit is the *last* one, Git stores the raw hash ID of the last commit under a branch name like `master`.  So the name `master` simply points to commit `H` now:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Just a moment ago, before you made commit `H`, the name `master` pointed to commit `H`.  The act of creating a new commit stores:

- a new snapshot,
- with you as the author and committer,
- "now" as the two date-and-time-stamps,
- your log message as the log message; and
- the previous branch-tip-commit as its parent.

The *content* in the new snapshot comes from the index.  What the index stores is not *differences:* it is the *next* commit snapshot, ready to be made.

When you run `git status`, Git runs `git diff` internally, to see what's *different* in the ready-to-make next commit, vs what's in the current commit.  Anything that's *different* here is listed as "changes to be committed"—but they're not *changes*, they are whole files.  At the same time, Git also runs a second `git diff` to compare the index's files to the work-tree's files.  Whatever is *different* here is listed as "changes not staged for commit"—but they're not *changes*, they are whole files.  The work-tree files are just in a form that you can see, and work with.  (The index copies are in a special Git-only form, ready to be committed.)

You have one "main" other Git you call `origin`.  With this Git, you call it up—or rather, have your Git call it up—now and then and your Git compares hash IDs with their Git.  If your Git has hash IDs that they don't have, your Git can give their Git those new commits.  Then, whether or not you gave them new commits, your Git can ask them, e.g., to *please set your `master` to point to commit `H`*.  (For this to work, you must first send them commit `H`.)  They either agree, and now they have new commit `H` and *their* `master` also points to (their copy of) commit `H`, or they say "no, I won't do that for ______" (fill in the blank with the reason).

#### How to get what you want

The simplest option is to add a *third* Git repository.  This third Git has no shared commits with your local repository, nor with the Git over at `origin`: your Git and the `origin` Git keep sharing commits, which are uniquely identified by their hash IDs, and which connect to each other through these backwards-pointing links inside each commit.  This third Git has not met your Git before and has all-different hash IDs in *its* history: none of them are the same as any of your commits's IDs (by definition, as all commit hash IDs are unique everywhere unless the commit itself has been shared directly).

So, after you use `git remote add` to add a name and URL for this third Git, you can then run `git fetch name`—use the name you used in the `git remote add` command—to obtain *all* the commits from their Git.  Here I'll use the name `third` (although that's not a very good name).  For simplicity, let's assume you have a grand total of eight commits, which we'll call `A` through `H`, and that they have just three, which we'll call `N`, `O`, and `P`; and that you have one branch name, `master`, and so do they.  Your Git will obtain their three commits so that you now have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

N--O--P
```

Note that none of their commits connect to any of yours, nor vice versa: these are unrelated histories.  Now that you have their three commits, though, your Git needs to create a *name* to remember that `third`'s `master` points to commit `P`.  Your Git will use the name `third/master` (or whatever name you used), so you now have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master

N--O--P   <-- third/master
```

I added `origin/master` because your Git is presumably remembering that `origin`'s `master` points to commit `H`, too, so your Git now has two of these *remote-tracking names:* `origin/master` remembering `H`, and `third/master` remembering `P`.

The problem now is that you'd like (some) files to come out of commit `P`.  If you just do:

```
git checkout third/master
```

Git will put you in "detached HEAD" mode after:

- removing all of *your* files from the index and work-tree, and
- copying all the files from commit `P` into the index and work-tree

which leaves you with none of your files anywhere you can work with them.  You can then:

```
git checkout master
```

to have your Git remove from the index all of `P`'s files, remove them all from the work-tree, and refill the index and your work-tree from `H`'s files.

That's not much help.  Sure, everything is back to the way you need to work with *your* stuff, but you can't see their files!  They're back to being hidden inside commit `P`.  There are several things you *can* do here though, and the most direct one is:

```
git checkout third/master -- <paths>
```

where the `<paths>` arguments tell Git which *files* to extract from commit `P`.  This form of `git checkout` *does not* change your *current commit*, so you will still have your `master`, and therefore commit `H`, checked out.  What it does do instead is extract the named files—including entire directories-full of files, if `<paths>` names some directory or set of directories: all the files in that sub-tree will get extracted—with the contents of the files going into *both* your index *and* your work-tree.

So, if everything you want from commit `P` is in, say, `foo/`, just use:

```
git rm -rf foo/
git checkout third/master -- foo/
```

and you're ready to commit the updated files: everything in `foo/` has just come out of commit `P`.  The `git rm -rf foo/` step tells Git to delete all of *your* files, which you only need if there are some files in your `foo/` that aren't in commit `P`'s `foo/` (and you want those files to be gone).

If you need to be much more selective—if `foo/` is not sufficient—you might want to:

- use `git worktree add` to make a new work-tree containing commit `P`, or
- not use this `third` remote method at all: just clone their repository in some other location, and selectively copy files from that clone into your clone, then `git add` the copied files.

Note that if you use a separate (fourth!) clone, it becomes impossible to accidentally push the `N-O-P` chain of commits from your Git to your Git's `origin`, as they never exist anywhere in your Git.  If you do add a remote named `third`, those extra commits *still* won't go over to `origin` unless you do one of these two things:<sup>1</sup>

- make some of your own branches use those commits (directly, by pointing to them, or indirectly, by merging the unrelated history into your own commit history), or
- set one or more of your own local branch names to point to their commit(s)

*and* then `git push` these local branch names to `origin`.  That is, you have to first put `N-O-P` (or any other third-party Git repo commits) *into* your own history, then ask your Git to send your history—your commits—to `origin` and ask their Git to remember one of these new commits under some name (usually, branch name, but any name—branch, tag, whatever—suffices).

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also deliberately send the entire `N-O-P` chain by doing:

```
git push origin <hash-of-P>:<name>
```

where `<name>` is the name you want their (`origin`'s) Git to set after they receive the `N-O-P` chain.  But presumably you won't do that...